# request_callback_answer() - pyrogram системная возможность нажатия на кнопки от имени пользователя

Tags: python, telegram

Возникла потребность в нажатии на кнопку через pyrogram (user-бота). Вообще мне требуется нажимать как на inline-кнопки, так и на reply-кнопки. Я понимаю что это должно выполняться через функцию:

app.request_callback_answer(), но как именно заполнить последний аргумент, не совсем понятно, если там требуется callback_data, то как я могу её получить что бы потом использовать.